# Asp.net mvc is loosely coupled and full control over html

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In mvc, how can we say that loosely couple and full control over html, can any body explain me, any reference , i searched in google but it is not clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

- loosely couple

ASP.NET MVC works with abstractions over the standard HttpContext classes such as HttpContextBase, HttpRequestBase, HttpResponseBase, HttpSessionBase which allows for easier unit testing in isolation because those classes are abstract and can be mocked. In classic ASP.NET WebForms it is much harder to unit test the code because it relies on the real ASP.NET context classes which are close to impossible to mock as they require a real context in order to work. IMHO this is one of the best things about ASP.NET MVC compared to classic WebForms.

Also you have a clearer separation between the various aspects: model logic, view logic and controller logic. This doesn't mean that in classic WebForms you cannot achieve this separation. It's just a bit harder if you follow the standard approach which is to put everything in the view and the code behind.

- full control over html

Contrary to classic ASP.NET WebForms where you place a UserControl in the WebForm which generates the HTML for you at runtime (with far or less control over this generated HTML), in ASP.NET MVC View, it is you that are writing the HTML thus you can write whatever HTML you like.

Answer (score 0):

weel though your question is very ambiguous still i assume you are comparing with asp.net and that you have read this line somewhere on the internet.

1. Loosely coupled - this largely goes for units that are being used to develop a full web site. in Asp.net MVC or any other MVC pattern for that matter MVC itself stands for Model-View-Controller so this is separation of concerns and the fact that each item is don't what it means to do ie-view handles all the ui layer means that each separate entity can be tested individually.
2. full control over HTML - in traditional asp.net the markup was generate by the asp.net framework as many server controls were used. in asp.net MVC all the markup is written or atleast is editable by the user

to get a feel over it read more about MVC pattern and how its being used in asp.net MVC

Answer (score 0):

The two ideas are (somewhat) separate. That may be where your confusion lies.

ASP.NET MVC (and the MVC paradigm in general) is considered loosely coupled due to the fact that each concern - the Model, View, and Controller - handles different aspects of an application. The Model = Data, the View = the User Interface, and the Controller manages the interaction between those two and business logic (which can further be separated if you go with the onion paradigm of MVC have additional sub-layers). This separation of concerns allows for improved user testing, mocking, and ease of refactoring that you don't have with WebForms (or at least not as easily).

The reason that you get full control over the HTML is due to the history of ASP.NET. ASP.NET originally began with WebForms. WebForms were created in response to developers who very much liked the "drag and drop" and "point and click" paradigm of the applications that they were able to create. Drag a button onto the screen, double click to get an action associated with it, write some code, done! It was easy.

At the same time, this ease hid *a lot* of underlying "stuff" that was happening. HTTP, by design, is stateless. WebForms specifically hid all that statelessness, and actually tried to make HTTP appear stateful, through a number of different techniques which revolve around managing ViewState. In addition, this drag and drop paradigm removed the control that folks had over their HTML directly. ASP.NET MVC "fixes" that (some don't consider this a fix - it depends on what you care about) by having you write the HTML directly in the View. Hence...more control.

Some other good information about the WebForms model here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46031/why-does-the-asp-net-web-forms-model-suck